# Set Image as backgroundto lock screen and regular screen

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I'm new to mobile development - so sorry if my question is stupid.
I want to make an application which will can change (set new Image) background for lock screen and regular screen (desktop background)

Questions are:

1) If I can do it? Because I read one topic and had seen that somebody wrote that music application(media services) can change background only/ If it right?

2) If I can - can you give me some code example or just link to right topic?

BTW I'm junior in mobile dev, but have hard prog. skills,

Thank you.
Regards,
David.

Answer (score 2):

To set background image:

```
WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager;
myWallpaperManager.SetBitmap (bitmapToDisplay);
```

Before setting an Image maybe you should resize it to the proper dimensions for the current Device,
Check this [article](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/resources/general/load_large_bitmaps_efficiently/) for handling large bitmaps efficiently

For the lock screen maybe this [component](https://components.xamarin.com/view/lock-screen) is useful but i don't know if there is another native way of changing the image in the lock screen